# Collision between a static and a moving object

Tags: java, swing, collision, maze

I am building a maze game and here I have a simple map...

Til there there's no problem but my issue is with collision

This is my map:

[image]

Here I have built the map myself with this code:

```
package maze;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Rectangle;

public class Maze1 extends GameObject{

    public Maze1(int x, int y, ID id) {
        super(x, y, id);
    }

    public void tick() {

    }

    public void render(Graphics g){
        Font fnt = new Font("arial", 1, 25);
        g.setFont(fnt);
        g.drawString("Level : 1",165 , 433);

        //x, y, WIDTH, HEIGHT
        g.setColor(Color.darkGray); 
        g.fillRect(65, 65, 130 ,15); 
        g.fillRect(0, 130, 145 ,15); 
        g.fillRect(195, 195, 400 ,15);
        g.fillRect(65, 195, 80 ,15); 
        g.fillRect(130, 260, 80 ,15); 
        g.fillRect(65, 325, 195 ,15); 
        g.fillRect(325, 325, 80 ,15); 

        // x, y, WIDTH, HEIGHT

        g.fillRect(195, 130, 80 ,80); 
        g.fillRect(260, 0, 145 ,80);  

        //x, y, HEIGHT, WIDTH

        g.fillRect(65, 145, 15 ,130); 
        g.fillRect(195, 65, 15 ,195); 
        g.fillRect(260, 260, 15 ,130);
        g.fillRect(325, 130, 15 ,80); 
        g.fillRect(325, 260, 15 ,65); 


        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.fillRect(0, -20, 500 ,32); //x, y, WIDTH, HEIGHT
        g.fillRect(0, 390, 500 ,15); 
        g.fillRect(0, Game.HEIGHT - 41, 500 ,30); 
        g.fillRect(-20, 0, 32 ,500);
        g.fillRect(Game.WIDTH -18, 0, 32 ,340);
        g.fillRect(Game.WIDTH -18, 400, 32 ,100);
    }
}
```

This collision code is for the top-right hand corner rectangle

I've tried two different types of collision codes but none of then tend to work

Collision code :

```
public void collision() {
    if(this.getX() >=229 && this.getY() <= 79) {
        if(this.getX() >=229) {
            this.setVelX(0);
            this.setVelY(0);
            this.setX(this.getX() -1);
        }

        if(this.getY() <= 79){
            this.setVelX(0);
            this.setVelY(0);
            this.setY(this.getY() +1);
        }       
    }
```

Here when the player hits the rectangle from the left side the player moves down and when the player hits the rectangle from the bottom side the player moves to the left.

I've tried the same code with an if, else if statement but it still doesn't work. When the player hits the left side it works perfectly but when the player hits the rectangle from the bottom side it teleports to the edge of the rectangle.

I hope my description is clear enough for you to picture my situation.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: shouldn't it be this.getX() >=229 **&&** this.getY() <= 79

Comment: Woops... forgot to type that, but I still have the same problem

Comment: Read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ for some tips about how to debug your code.

Comment: I see. In any case, you will need to provide more code and information for someone to help you. Consider adding the libraries (including version) that you are using and How you are storing the maze (is it a tile map or code-generated rectangles)? Additional information and a sample code which someone else might be able to run on their system is important.

Comment: You need to track all setX() and setY() method calls. Maybe you are setting them from other parts of the application.

Comment: I recommend storing a list of lines representing each segment where gray meets green, and making a method to check to see if your rectangle is intersecting a line. That way, you can store your old location, check to see if your new location is intersecting any walls, and if it is change back to your old location. If you're interested in this, I can post an answer giving more detail, I just didn't post this as an answer to begin with because it doesn't really answer your question.

Comment: @FlexEast if it isn't a problem do you mind me asking for the answer

Comment: No problem, it'll take me a little bit to write up

Comment: Don't worry I have time... thanks

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: I hope my answer helps you! It might be a little lengthy, but I tried to make it as easy to understand as possible.

Answer (score 1):

For collision detection, I recommend keeping your map data in list of rectangles. Something like:

```
public class Rect {
    public int topLeftX;
    public int topLeftY;
    public int width;
    public int height;

    public Rect(int x, int y, int w, int h){
        topLeftX = x;
        topLeftY = y;
        width = w;
        height = h;
    }


    //Ignore the code below here for now


    public boolean collidingWith(int x, int y, int width, int height){ 
        Rect r = new Rect(x, y, width, height);
        boolean rLeftInWidth = r.topLeftX > topLeftX && r.topLeftX < topLeftX + width;
        boolean rRightInWidth = r.topLeftX + r.width > topLeftX && r.topLeftX + width < topLeftX + width;
        boolean rTopInHeight = r.topLeftY > topLeftY && r.topLeftY < topLeftY + width;
        boolean rBottomInHeight = r.topLeftY + r.width > topLeftY && r.topLeftY + width < topLeftY + width;


        if(rLeftInWidth || rRightInWidth){
            //If there is horizantal overlap between the other rectangle and this one
            if(rTopInHeight || rBottomInHeight){
                //If there is also vertical overlap then we must be colliding
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

You then keep your rectangles in an array or some kind of collection, ArrayList is probably easiest.

```
ArrayList<Rect> wallData = new ArrayList<Rect>();
```

You then can add your map data. This is taken from your rectangle painting:

```
g.fillRect(65, 65, 130 ,15);
```

It becomes a rectangle, with the same arguments. You can even do this before filling in the rectangles and reuse it.

```
wallData.add(new Rect(65, 65, 130, 15));
Rect r = wallData.get(0);
g.fillRect(r.topLeftX, r.topLeftY, r.width, r.height);
```

So, now that you have this data, how do you use it? When you want to check for collisions, simply loop through your list of rectangles and check to see if you player is colliding.

```
for(Rect rectangle: wallData){
    if(rectangle.collidingWith(<playerX>, <playerY>, <playerWidth>, <playerHeight>)){
        //Your player is colliding with a rectangle!
    }
}
```

Remember that section earlier I told you to ignore? Let's go over that now.
It's simpler than it looks, I swear!

```
    public boolean collidingWith(int x, int y, int width, int height){ 
        Rect r = new Rect(x, y, width, height);
        boolean rLeftInWidth = r.topLeftX > topLeftX && r.topLeftX < topLeftX + width;
        boolean rRightInWidth = r.topLeftX + r.width > topLeftX && r.topLeftX + width < topLeftX + width;
        boolean rTopInHeight = r.topLeftY > topLeftY && r.topLeftY < topLeftY + width;
        boolean rBottomInHeight = r.topLeftY + r.width > topLeftY && r.topLeftY + width < topLeftY + width;


        if(rLeftInWidth || rRightInWidth){
            //If there is horizantal overlap between the other rectangle and this one
            if(rTopInHeight || rBottomInHeight){
                //If there is also vertical overlap then we must be colliding
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

We start out by figuring out if overlaps horizantally. For example, the following are overlapping horizantally, but not vertically.

```
=-----=
-     -
-     -
-------
   +------
   -     -
   -     -
   -------
```

You can tell because the corner with the plus is in between the corners with equals. The four booleans just hold whether or not our corners are between the other object's corner.

```
boolean rLeftInWidth = r.topLeftX > topLeftX && r.topLeftX < topLeftX + width;
```

This becomes true if our top left corner is in between the other rectangles top left and top right corners. We then do that for a right corner as well. If either one is true, then we're overlapping horizantally!

From there, we just check to see if it's overlapping both horizontally AND vertically. If it is, it's colliding, like this!

```
-------
-     -
-   ------
-----    -
    -    -
    ------
```

Now, what do you do when you realize your player is colliding? This takes a bit of work, but nothing special. Before you move the player by adding their velocity to their location, simply save their location.

```
private int playerX;
private int playerY;

<method where you change it>{
    playerX = <playerX>;
    playerY = <playerY>;
    <change their location according to velocity>
}
```

Now, if the player collides with a wall, just set their location back to the values you just saved, and set their velocity to 0!

It's a bit complicated to set up, but once you get it going it's a nice solution.

In this answer, I put a bunch of stuff in between <>. That just means that you need that value or that's where what it says happens.

I hope this helps you! If you have any questions, don't hesitate to ask, I'd love to help out more. Collision detection is a complicated subject, with lots of approaches. This is typically the one I find easiest for simple applications.

Pros of this approach vs your original:

- You can setup your rectangles before painting and use them for painting as well as collision detection.

If you have your list of rectangles created, you can use a loop to paint them:

```
for(Rect r: wallData){
    g.fillRect(r.topLeftX, r.topLeftY, r.width, r.height);
}
```

- Ease of editing: if you ever decide to change your map, you only have to change some rectangles width, height and position instead of going through a bunch of if statements trying to figure out if that's the right one to change. (I've gone through that before)
- Less error prone: it's a lot easier to set up some rectangles rather than a ton of if statements for each wall.

Cons of this approach vs. your original

- This one is less efficient--there are more operations for checking to see if the player is colliding with a rectangle rather than 2 ifs. Also, there may be rectangles that the player can't collide with. However, the loss in efficiency is very small, especially with the low number of rectangles in your map.
- This one is more complicated. It's better to learn about the code you use, rather than just blindly copy-paste. If you need to make changes, it'll be harder if you don't understand. (Not that you don't, it just might be a little harder.)